# Archive Site pages

Tags: category-archive

I'm really new to expression engine.  I mostly just do basic updates and some minor basic coding (html/css).  Nothing with the templates, but I do have access.  We have the website hosted through an agency that costs a lot of money to make an changes or updates, so my supervisor wants us to archive web pages ourselves.

Currently we have over 10,000 pages.  We host blogs for 15 different parts of the company.  Is there a way that we can archive these without deleting them?  I saw there was a plugin to get, but I think that would involve the agency we use.  Our supervisor suggested copying and pasting all the old blogs into a word doc then just deleting them, but I feel like that's really time consuming.

Any suggestions on how to archive the web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

- First you set up your own archive the site - if you have FTP access to the site you could simply copy off all the template and asset files and grab a copy of the SQL database file (the config.php for the site - which you can see if you can FTP to get the templates - contains login and location information for the SQL database being used).  Then you can create your own version of the site on a server you control (if you are not worried about speed, then any mac or linux computer can do this out of the box).  You should be doing something like this anyway just as part of best-practice (your own offline backup).  If you do this you'll end up with a fully dynamic copy of the site.
- Second, and maybe more easily, you could simply crawly the existing sites / pages and build a static archive of every page.  This is something you can do using command-line mac/linux tools but very much easier if you use an app such as [sitesucker](http://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/) - which makes it straightforward to set the options to get you what you want.  It's simple, works well, and generates a heap of files in folders that you can them simply browse as a static version of your site directly using a browser.

Personally - I'd do both.

HTH.